# Pythonic list comprehension possible with this loop?

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I have a love/hate relationship with list comprehension.  On the one hand I think they are neat and elegant.  On the other hand I hate reading them.  (especially ones I didn't write) I generally follow the rule of, make it readable until speed is required. So my question is really academic at this point.

I want a list of stations from a table who's strings often have extra spaces. I need those spaces stripped out. Sometimes those stations are blank and should not be included.

```
stations = []
for row in data:
    if row.strip():
        stations.append(row.strip())
```

Which translates to this list comprehension:

```
stations = [row.strip() for row in data if row.strip()]
```

This works well enough, but it occurs to me that I'm doing strip twice.  I guessed that .strip() was not really needed twice and is generally slower than just assigning a variable.

```
stations = []
for row in data:
    blah = row.strip()
    if blah:
        stations.append(blah)
```

Turns out I was correct.

```
> Striptwice list comp 14.5714301669     
> Striptwice loop 17.9919670399
> Striponce loop 13.0950567955
```

Timeit shows between the two loop segments, the 2nd (strip once) is faster.  No real surprise here.  I am surprised that list comprehension is only marginally slower even though it's doing a strip twice.

My question: **Is there a way to write a list comprehension that only does the strip once?**

**Results:**

Here are the timing results of the suggestions

```
# @JonClements & @ErikAllik
> Striptonce list comp 10.7998494348
# @adhie
> Mapmethod loop 14.4501044569
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how the suggested answers compare time-wise to your tests

Comment: I will.  I just got back to my post this morning and hadn't looked at anything all weekend.

Comment: Can't accept two answers.  I'm all for the underdog, so the credit goes to @ErikAllik even though JonClements was just as correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nested comprehensions can be tricky to read, so my first preference would be:

```
stripped = (x.strip() for x in data)
stations = [x for x in stripped if x]
```

Or, if you inline `stripped`, you get a single (nested) list comprehension:

```
stations = [x for x in (x.strip() for x in data) if x]
```

Note that the first/inner comprehension is a actually generator expression, which, in other words is a lazy list comprehension; this is to avoid iterating twice.

Comment: Similarly, `def stripped(iter): return (x.strip() for x in iter)`, then you can write `stations = list(x for x in stripped(data) if x)`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense if `stripped` will be used again later.

Comment: @SteveJessop Although naming the parameter `iterable` is more conventional and more importantly avoids shadowing the builtin `iter` in the function...

Comment: @JonClements: agreed. In my defence, I'm not well. It's probably for the best that I'm not working.

Answer (score 29):

There is - create a generator of the stripped strings first, then use that:

```
stations = [row for row in (row.strip() for row in data) if row]
```

You could also write it without a comp, eg (swap to `imap` and remove `list` for Python 2.x):

```
stations = list(filter(None, map(str.strip, data)))
```

Comment: So `None` stands for the ID function (`lambda x: x`) basically? Wasn't aware of such shortcut; thanks!

Comment: Btw that `list(...)` call is not necessary.

Comment: @ErikAllik for Python 3.x it is... I've noted it should be removed for  Python 2.x as well as the `map` being swapped to `imap` :)

Comment: I'm kicking myself just a little. I should have seen @JonClements first example.  Essentially Looping over the list twice. Very good sir.

Comment: @JonClements - I am having trouble getting your second example to work in 2.7 (which is what I primarily use).

Comment: @MarcelWilson: list comprehensions and generator expressions are preferred over `map` and `filter` anyway in idiomatic Python code; Jon probably just included it for completeness' sake, or as just additional information.

Comment: Unfortunately the strings are actually unicode. Which oddly means we can't map str.strip.  I'm not sure I understand why that makes a difference in map vs iterating over the list of unicode.

Comment: @warwaruk yup... or I suppose, `operator.methodcaller('strip')` but then we're at the stage that using the comprehensions are much nicer ;)

Comment: Better to `map(lambda x: x.strip)` for it to work polymorphically with anything that can `.strip()` (i.e. `str` as well as `unicode` in this case). But the list comprehension version is still better :)

Comment: @ErikAllik but then - might as well just use a comp and add the `()` and remove the whole `lambda` and map part - as the `filter`/`map` etc... builtins work nicely with other builtins and the `operator` module... As soon as we're using a `map` with a custom `lambda` - we should probably be looking back to comps

Comment: @JonClements: yeah, that's what I'm stressing—just always prefer comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Apply strip to all the elements using map() and filter after that.

```
[item for item in map(lambda x: x.strip(), list) if item]
```

Comment: that `map()` is not needed nor encouraged by the Python conventions/community; also, your code does 2 iterations.

Comment: Then transform it to the list comprehension form. In some functional languages, map is more lazy.

Comment: `map` is not lazy in Python but `itertools.imap` is.

Comment: @ErikAllik I'll just add that it is lazy in Python 3.x. However, it can also be lazy in 2.6+ with a `from future_builtins import map`